# How to add in date data?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with following fields:

```
TABLE dat(a int,dat date,freq int);
```

I want get a new value in ALIAS column by adding "dat" and "freq" data.
I tried in following ways:

```
select a,dat,freq,date(dat,"+5 Year") as Due_Date from dat;
```

which working fine result is:

```
2|2020-01-01|3|2025-01-01
```

But my object is to add freq value in dat value so I tried as follow:

```
select a,dat,freq,date(dat,"+freq Year") as Due_Date from dat;
```

which is not giving result and remain result as:

```
2|2020-01-01|3
```

so I need to know how possibly method to get my required result.

Answer (score 0):

You must concatenate `freq` to `' year'`:

```
SELECT a, dat, freq,
       date(dat, freq || ' year') AS Due_Date 
FROM dat;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0c784b8fd0f182ade6254b8112f2ef58).